# Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that $\frac{a-1}{b}+\frac{b-1}{c}+\frac{c-1}{a} \geq 0$

Tags: inequality

**Question**

Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that $$\frac{a-1}{b}+\frac{b-1}{c}+\frac{c-1}{a} \geq 0$$

**My try**

I have simplified this to the equivalent inequality $$ab^2+bc^2+ca^2 \geq ab+bc+ca$$

Now, I have tried AM-GM, but it does not work.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By AM-GM : $ab^2+2bc^2\ge 3bc, ...$

Comment: Nicer than my proof! ;)

Comment: Nicely done....

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hölder and AMGM to prove that $RHS \leq (ab)^{3/2}+(bc)^{3/2}+(ca)^{3/2}=IS$.

So we want to prove $IS \leq LHS$.

$IS=\sqrt{ab}\sqrt{ab^2}+\ldots \leq \left(IS * LHS\right)^{1/2}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach**: Let $$
X=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{b},\quad Y=\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab,\quad Z=\sum_{\text{cyc}}a.
$$ Then we have
$$
X+Y=\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)\ge 2\sum_{\text{cyc}}a=2Z,
$$ and
$$
XZ=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{b}\sum_{\text{cyc}}a=\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^2c\sum_{\text{cyc}}c\ge \left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}ac\right)^2=Y^2
$$ by AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz. Thus,
$$
X(X+Y)\ge 2XZ\ge 2Y^2,
$$and
$$
(X+2Y)(X-Y)\ge 0.
$$ This gives
$$
\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{b}=X\ge Y=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{b}.
$$